# SQL how to check is a value in a col is NOT in another table

Tags: sql, dashdb

Maybe I need another coffee because this seems so simple yet I cannot get my head around it.

Let's say I have a `tableA` with a `col1` where employee IDs are stored.... ALL employee IDs. And the 2nd table, `tableB` has `col2` which lists all employeeID who have a negative evaluation.

I need a query which returns all ID's from `col1` from `table1` and a newcol which show a '1' for those ID's which do NOT exist in col2 of TableB.

I am doing this in dashDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option uses a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables:

```
SELECT a.col1,
       CASE WHEN b.col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_col
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
    ON a.col1 = b.col2
```

Comment: @MikePala Maybe switch to double shot espresso :-)

Comment: brah.... I'm already running on quadruple :) ...maybe THAT"s the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can achieve your requirement with LEFT JOIN along with IFNULL function as below.

```
SELECT a.col1,
   IFNULL(b.col2, 1) NewCol
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
   ON a.col1 = b.col2
```